# try/throw/catch in c++: what's wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, try-catch

Please can you check this code? What's wrong with try/catch/throw?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int get_input();

int main() {

    int number, base_in, base_out;
    bool pass = 1;

    while(pass) {

        double number, base_in, base_out;

        try {

            cout << "What's your number? ";
            number = get_input();

            pass = 0;

        }
        catch(problem_type()) {
            cout << "Please, write inputs should be integer" << endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}


int get_input(bool target = 1) {

    double n;
    cin >> n;

    if(n != (int)n) throw problem_type();

    if(target) {
        if(n<1) throw problem_type();
    }

    return (int)n;

}
```

Comment: Change `catch(problem_type())` to `catch(const problem_type&)`

Answer (score 3):

You catch by type. Like

```
catch(const problem_type&){ }
```

That is, if `problem_type` is type. I see no definition anywhere…

Comment: @SethCarnegie, added `const`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, I think if it's non-const, it's copied if possible? I fail to remember the regulations around that — it's not the first time :)

Comment: I'm not sure, I'll see if I can find something on it. I was just thinking you can't bind a temporary to a non-`const` reference, but there might be an exception for exceptions.

Comment: **problem_type** is a name of function

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: Even if it is const, the implementation might make as many copy as it wants, to propagate the exception to the catch block.

Comment: @user1714920, still no definition. You should be catching the return type of the function then.

Comment: @user1714920, I don't fully understand your question. You probably can edit that like that and this like this ;-)

Comment: :) sorry, i don't have an idea how can i fix it

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker if you look at §15.1.1 they give an example where an object is thrown by value and caught by non-`const` reference so apparently it's OK.

Comment: Aha. Well, it makes perfect sense to use `const` anyway, so that implementation is less inclined to copy. But, as we know now, `problem_type` is a `problem_function` in fact ;-)

Comment: I have a function **get_input** to get inputs and checking. If somethings is wrong, it sends with **throw()**

Comment: @user1714920, it throws `problem_type()`. Whate `problem_type()` returns I have no faintest clue. You can `catch(decltype(problem_type()))` in c++11, but it is strange you don't know what your function is declared as.

Answer (score 0):

When an exception is throw you'll get a in memory object with info about the exception... so it's necessary to take it as `catch( const Type& error )`

Why is it as a reference? Think of the possible caotic state that would be on memory on some situations, so MAKE a copy of would add complications and processing time, you could loose vital info. So that's why we take it as a reference.

Just 'point' to original piece of data.